# Error Number 1046: No Database selected in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This `function run_blank_sql()` I have created for `Installing` the SQL file to the `Database`.
but this code `$this->load->database();` gives me an error.
`No database selected`.

I have also `autoloaded` the `Database`. `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');`

And also the `database` is connected in the `config/database.php`

```
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '********',
'database' => 'waqas',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
```

And the `database` is also created in `Mysql`.

```
  function run_blank_sql() {
        $this->load->database();
        // Set line to collect lines that wrap
        $templine = '';
        // Read in entire file
        $lines = file('./uploads/install.sql');
        // Loop through each line
        foreach ($lines as $line) {
          // Skip it if it's a comment
          if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '')
            continue;
          // Add this line to the current templine we are creating
          $templine .= $line;
          // If it has a semicolon at the end, it's the end of the query so can process this templine
          if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';') {
            // Perform the query
            $this->db->query($templine);
            // Reset temp variable to empty
            $templine = '';
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: check your password..! may be that is not valid.

Comment: this looks like a setup error in your database config file, which CI version are you using? And are using this on your localhost or on a production server? AND: how do you create the database (via cpanel or programmatically?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you haven't selected any default database for your project. That's why you are getting this error. For selecting your database you should specify at least one. mainly database is loaded inside the constructor. so now modify your code by below.

```
$this->db = $this->load->database("default",TRUE);
```